# htaccess rewrite to dist folder and set AngularJS html5mode true

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, html5mode

I have an application in AngularJS where I need to set html5mode to true in order to remove the hash `/#/` from URL. The application in minified version is found in the `dist` folder.

QUESTION: My goal is to rewrite traffic to the `dist` folder and to allow the enabling of the html5mode. Can anybody help?

I can get html5mode to work by setting
`<base href="/" />` and adding `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` to app config and at the bottom of ui-router file.

All of this works in development mode where it's using NodeJS through Gulp. 
When I move the application to other environments that are on Apache, the setup has problems.

The problems are:

A. The app can't load any assets because it's looking for them in the server root.

B. The app can't reload and land on the requested URL. It gives a 404 error.

Without the html5mode enabled in the app, I am using this htaccess to redirect to `dist`folder and it works fine.

```
# This first part is not relevant for the question but is included for practical purposes. It rewrites traffic to HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(app\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)dist
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dist/$1 [L]
```

It needs to work the same on the difference environments so that I can use it on local as well as other environments.
On local it would be on `localhost/project_name/app/webapp/(dist)` and in other environments it would be on `https://app.example.com/(dist)`

I also tried setting `<base href="/dist/" />` but it also doesn't work. It only adds `dist` folder to the assets path and would also not be usable in development because the app is then not served from `dist`.

Basically the parts work but when put together it fails.

I went through many SO answers already without success:

[in html5mode(true) views are not loading in page refresh in angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34630233/in-html5modetrue-views-are-not-loading-in-page-refresh-in-angular-js)

[AngularJS + html5Mode + custom fallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666038/angularjs-html5mode-custom-fallback)

[angularjs ngroute with html5mode(true) on apache fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31660533/angularjs-ngroute-with-html5modetrue-on-apache-fails)

[AngularJS: html5Mode(true) causing 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21973802/angularjs-html5modetrue-causing-404-error)

Comment: You are using Apache? Create a new VHOST which is pointing directly into your `dist` folder. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than struggling with rewrite rules, if you have Apache2, define a *fallbackresource* instead.

This two lines of code in the .htaccess file will solve your issue:

```
FallbackResource /index.php
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

*The second line is necessary because of Google Chrome only.*

[To learn more about fallback resources, see the Apache documentation here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource)